# Upload a file to a sharepoint list from code

Tags: development, sharepoint-server

How can I upload a file to a SharePoint list from code? I need to upload a file as an attachment to the list item through code.

I use an ASP: FileUpload for the search and selection of the file but how can I save that file in the list?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
byte[] contents = ...//your file's byte[]
SPAttachmentCollection attachments = item.Attachments;
attachments.Add("AttachmentName.txt", contents);
```

[Reference](https://nehasinha.wordpress.com/2008/05/23/programmticallyc-adding-deleting-copying-and-downloading-attachments-in-splist/)